# Swich branch when cloned only latest snapshot

Tags: git

Due to big size of the repo I cloned only latest snapshot of it:

```
git clone --depth=1 <url>
```

This command downloaded only latest version of `master` branch. So I fetched the branch I needed:

```
git fetch --depth=1 origing testing
```

With such output:

```
remote: Enumerating objects: 13, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From gitlab.com:lambda-hse/tatlin-hse/gotatlin
 * branch            testing    -> FETCH_HEAD
```

The problem is when I do (for changing branch I am on):

```
git checkout testing
```

nothing happens and repo is still on the `master` branch. How can I overcome this problem without full cloning of the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you may notice in the output, git fetched the sha1 of your branch but did not create the reference locally, is is just in the FETCH_HEAD

```
* branch            testing    -> FETCH_HEAD
```

fro then, if you do `git log FETCH_HEAD` you'll see the head of you distant branch.

You can recreate the branch locally by specifying both destination and source by giving the full path:

```
git fetch --depth=1 origin refs/heads/testing:refs/heads/testing
```

and then

```
git checkout testing
```

Comment: what means refs/heads/<branchname>:?

Comment: this is where git stores 'references' to branches; have a look to your ` .git/refs/heads/` directory. You can also notice that files in there just contain the sha1 of the 'top' of your branch, this is how git keeps track of branches.